# n number of column wise subtraction

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, data.table

need help in N number or column wise subtraction, Below are the columns in a input dataframe.

input dataframe:

```
A   B   C   D
1   4   6   2
3   3   3   4
1   2   2   2
4   4   4   4
5   2   3   2
```

Expected Output:

```
A      B-A     C-B      D-C
1       3       2       -4
3       0       0       1
1       1       0       0
4       0       0       0
5       -3      1       -1
```

similarly there will be many column upto 10.

i am able to write the code for 2 columns:

Code:

```
df$(B-A) <- df$B - df$A
df$(C-B) <- df$C - df$B
```

and so on... but in this should come in loop as there are almost 10 to 12 columns. Please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a Vectorized way to do this,

```
cbind.data.frame(df[1], df[-1] - df[-ncol(df)])
```

which gives,

> ```
>   A  B C  D
> 1 1  3 2 -4
> 2 3  0 0  1
> 3 1  1 0  0
> 4 4  0 0  0
> 5 5 -3 1 -1
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the instructive/pedagogic straightforward solution:

```
df <- data.frame(A=c(1,3,1,4,5),  B=c(4,3,2,4,2), C=c(6,3,2,4,3),  D=c(2,4,2,4,2))
df
```

Get the pattern:

```
cbind(df[1], df[2] - df[1], df[3] - df[2], df[4] - df[3]) # solved
```

Now, use dynamic programming in R to finish (in the general case):

```
cbind(df[1], sapply(1:(ncol(df)-1), function(i) df[i+1] - df[i]))
```

Output:

```
  A  B C  D
1 1  3 2 -4
2 3  0 0  1
3 1  1 0  0
4 4  0 0  0
5 5 -3 1 -1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `apply()` you can also try this

```
cbind(df[1], t(apply(df, 1, diff)))
```

Output:

```
  A  B C  D
1 1  3 2 -4
2 3  0 0  1
3 1  1 0  0
4 4  0 0  0
5 5 -3 1 -1
```